# Take Control of Process via SSH

Tags: command-line, ssh, process

I've started a process via SSH that it seems will take 2-3 days. I've not started this via tmux, so if my connection dies, my task will need to start over.

Is there anyway I can login to another SSH session and take control of this process in a tmux session, close the original SSH session and have the process continue to run?

Comment: I didn't get it, how tmux didn't work for you?

Comment: I've started a process in a normal SSH session, not a tmux session. I'm looking to see if it is possible to assume a process via a tmux session.

Answer (score 1):

`byobu` or `tmux` are terminal multiplexers. Byobu is ex. screen. It has both `byobu-screen` and `byobu-tmux`.

1. Login using ssh
2. Run the multiplexer

   ```
   byobu-screen
   ```
3. Then run your commands
4. Use other tab in the multiplexer to detach:

   ```
   byobu-screen -d
   ```
5. Now your are back to SSH session if you use `ps ax` you can see it still running. You can now `exit` from SSH session.

To resume:

1. Login using ssh
2. Resume the multiplexer

   ```
   byobu-screen -r
   ```

   Then you are where you was. You can open multiple multiplexer session and they will stay running (as they are in background). So open one, detach then another one, detach, try resume.
3. Back to your commands
4. Use other tab in the multiplexer to detach again:

   ```
   byobu-screen -d
   ```
5. You can now `exit` from SSH session. Leaving you commands running.

See for Reference https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen